Azure databricks clusters are failing to load while creating a linked service in azure data factory
This is  the error
I'm trying to learn azure data bricks, data factory...
I'm trying to link the data bricks cluster to data factory, but the clusters are failing to load, I've entered the cluster name manually but it is giving the above error. Access token is correct, everything is perfect. But I don't know what's going wrong.....
Please help me with this...

If you are using access token, the access token should be a 36 character length string something like "dipiaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".  If you have entered a correct token, the clusters available to you should come as s drop down. If you are entering the cluster name manually, it means that your access token is incorrect. From your  picture it looks like you have only entered 10 characters.

I do agree with @Anupam Chand, the above error will occur when you give the wrong Access token.

In the above, when the access token is wrong then you can't get the existing cluster ID in the drop down. When you give wrong access token, it will say Invalid access token in the error. But when you miss the dapi before the token, it will give the above error. In both cases, you can't get the existing cluster drop down.
So, make sure you give the total token dapiXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX that you copied from databricks workspace.
You will see the existing cluster IDs from the drop down like below.

